# Bind call unbound method with object dynamically

Tags: python

```
class MyClass(Object):
    def my_method(self):
        return 'works :)'
```

now I have:

```
method = MyClass.my_method
my_class_obj = MyClass()
```

but I'll know the value of 'method' in runtime (its about pytest parametrization, and i want to parametrize with methods, not strings (just not tobe prone to sting change). Therefore I cannot do:
my_class_obj.my_method
just because I don't know that method name yet:
I've managed to do this code, but it looks like working around...

```
getattr(obj, str(MyClass.my_method.__name__))()
>>>'works :)'
```

For properties I use `fget()` and I am simply looking same approach for methods as well.

Comment: >{i want to parametrize with methods, not strings (just not tobe prone to sting change)} I don't think I understand this part. Could you elaboarate please?

Comment: The only thing different about an unbound method is that it doesn't automatically supply the first (traditionally `self`) argument.  So do that yourself: `method(my_class_obj)`.

Comment: YES! I really worked around such simple solution, didn't I? Thank you @jasonharper! :)